# Laravel response->json() corrupts valid json?

Tags: php, json, laravel

I think it's a very simple thing but I can not figure out how to do it.
what I do is essentially this:

```
$ads= Ad::query()->select(['category_id', 'title', 'start_date'])->where(['account_id'=>$id])->get();
        $ads= json_encode($ads);
        return response()->json($ads, 200);
```

The result of this is:

```
"[{"category_id":1,"title":"Scacchi","start_date":1517982647},{"category_id":1,"title":"test test test","start_date":null}]"
```

That is a string and not a valid json because of the external quotation marks, which were added by the json () function since $ads after the json_encode is a valid json.

How can I prevent this strange behavior?

Comment: Remove/Commented this line of code `ads= json_encode($ads);`

Comment: is the first thing I tried to do thinking that json () was already converting but not. If I delete that line in the response I get an array

Comment: First of all, I really recommend you to use Eloquent... use relations and you would only write one or two short calls, not a long query, that is definitely the idea of laravel... and second, if you return a collection, you pass that to the `response()->json(HERE)` as a param (you don't event need to do `,200`, it is already a default... you must read what is the method doing before changing things... understand it... then change it...

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing out that parameter 200 is superfluous. What do you mean to use Eloquent? Could you show me how to rewrite the first line using Eloquent? I used this syntax precisely because I would like to avoid having a collection, in fact I do not understand why I should hydrate a collection if I can have a simple array and then convert it to json.

Answer (score 1):

Just return it directly;

```
$ads= Ad::query()->select(['category_id', 'title', 'start_date'])->where(['account_id'=>$id])->get();

return $ads;
```

it should be json ,

UDPATE:

with a response json, do this:

```
return response()->json([
    'data' => $ads 
]);
```

Comment: I use response()->json() because it set the content-type header to application/json and i need it.

Comment: @topogigio, I updated it, try it, of course you have to use 'data' to get your records

Answer (score 0):

There should be an array inside response->json() function so, you should convert your result to array and pass it in response.

$ads= Ad::query()->select(['category_id', 'title', 'start_date'])->where(['account_id'=>$id])->get()->toArray();

return response()->json($ads, 200);